# Scala - pattern match against a type parameter?

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching

If I want to avoid the `isInstanceOf & asInstanceOf` combo, and instead want to use pattern matching, is there any *simple* way to avoid the erasure problem in the following example?  I researched some answers but they all seem to use Manifest and the resulting code looked more complex than the undesirable `isInstanceOf & asInstanceOf` combo.

```
trait Comparable[A] extends Ordered[A] {
  override def equals(that : Any) = 
    that match {
      case that : A => compare(that) == 0
      case _ => false
    }
}
```

My goal in the code above is to create a single trait that adds implementation for == and != to the ordered comparators.  However, I get the following error because A gets erased:

```
warning: abstract type pattern A is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
      case that : A => compare(that) == 0
```

NOTE: there are other similar questions on StackOverflow regarding this issue, but the accepted answers seem to use Manifest, hence my question - can this be achieved in a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no simpler way. `Manifest` has been replaced by `ClassTag` and `TypeTag`, but there isn't any easy way to get the needed `ClassTag` - traits can't take parameters, and `equals` in `Any` wasn't declared to take an implicit `ClassTag`, so we have to force the implementing class to provide it:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait Comparable[A] extends Ordered[A] {
  implicit def ct: ClassTag[A]

  override def equals(that: Any) = 
    that match {
      case that: A => compare(that) == 0
      case _ => false
    }
}
```

`isInstanceOf` won't help either, it will still require the `ClassTag`.

Comment: What do you mean by "equals in Any was declared to take an implicit ClassTag"? It just takes an `Any`.